# Render two json objects to the view with Play! scala 2.3

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.3

Here is a dumb question : I simply want to render two `Json object` to the view, I manage to do render them separately but not together...

I tried a simple trick like that (I tried with two '+' as well):

```
def totalToPay = Action { 
    Ok(Json.toJson(Account4686.findAllWithCredit()) + Json.toJson(Account403.findAllByOrgaIdWithCredit(1)))
}
```

but without success. I have this compilation error : `[error] /home/sim/dev/ticketapp/app/controllers/Admin.scala:136: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.json.JsValue
[error]  required: String`.

What is the correct way to perform this?

Comment: Always post the compilation error.

Comment: You mean merge the two json ? such as `{a: 1} merge {b: 2} => {a: 1, b: 2}`

Comment: `++` (merge) is method of `JsObject`, so you have to cast the two `JsValue` to `JsObject`

Comment: No I don't want to merge the two Json, just render it together to the view like [{a: 1}, {b: 2}].

Comment: So you want to create an array containing the two objects? Then do that: `JsArray(Json.toJson(...), Json.toJson(..))` (spray syntax, but I imagine the play syntax is similar).

Comment: Yep I'm looking for something like this, but in Play framework JsArray take only one argument of type Seq[JsValue] and I don't find the proper method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `JsArray` constructor that takes in a `Seq[JsValue]` as such:

```
JsArray(Seq(Json.toJson(obj1), Json.toJson(obj2))
```

Or if you want to use a `JsObject` instead of an array, you can do:

```
Json.obj("obj1" -> obj1, "obj2" -> obj2)
```

To merge two objects, you can use `++`:

```
Json.toJson(obj1).asInstanceOf[JsObject] ++ Json.toJson(obj2).asInstanceOf[JsObject]
```